# No Overload for Method. What am i Doing Wrong?

Tags: c#, class, methods

No Overload for Method. What am i Doing Wrong?
my head alread hurts :)

```
//this is the first class named Employee
namespace lala
{
public class Employee
{
    public static double GrossPay(double WeeklySales) //grosspay
    {

        return WeeklySales * .07;
    }

    public static double FedTaxPaid(double GrossPay)
    {
        return GrossPay * .18;
    }

    public static double RetirementPaid(double GrossPay)
    {
        return GrossPay * .1;
    }

    public static double SocSecPaid(double GrossPay)
    {
        return GrossPay * .06;
    }

    public static double TotalDeductions(double SocSecPaid, double RetirementPaid, double FedTaxPaid)
    {
        return SocSecPaid + RetirementPaid + FedTaxPaid;
    }

    public static double TakeHomePay(double GrossPay, double TotalDeductions)
    {
        return GrossPay - TotalDeductions;
    }
}
```

}

this is the second class named EmployeeApp
this is where i dont know why my program doesnt work

```
namespace lala
{
public class EmployeeApp
{
    public static string name;
    public static double WeeklySales;

    public static void Main()
    {
        Employee yuki = new Employee();

        GetInfo();

        Console.WriteLine();

        Console.WriteLine("Name: {0}", name);

        Console.WriteLine();

        Console.WriteLine("Gross Pay            : {0}", yuki.GrossPay());

        Console.WriteLine("Federal Tax Paid     : {0}", yuki.FedTaxPaid());
        Console.WriteLine("Social Security Paid : {0}", yuki.SocSecPaid());
        Console.WriteLine("Retirement Paid      : {0}", yuki.RetirementPaid());
        Console.WriteLine("Total Deductions     : {0}", yuki.TotalDeductions());

        Console.WriteLine();

        Console.WriteLine("Take-Home Pay        : {0}", yuki.TakeHomePay());

        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    public static string GetInfo()
    {
        Console.Write("Enter Employee Name : ");
        name = Console.ReadLine();

        Console.Write("Enter your Weekly Sales : ");
        WeeklySales = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());

        return name;
    }
}
```

}

any help would gladly be appreciated :)

Comment: What error are you getting, and what line is it pointing to?

Comment: You are calling `yuki.GrossPay(/* No parameter? */)` which is not overloaded for this. The method definition is `GrossPay(double WeeklySales)`.
And other methods also

Comment: Why are your methods marked as static?

Comment: in the second program when i try to call the yuki.GrossPay() and the other. i get 'No Overload Method takes 0 arguments'

Comment: The methods used in TotalDeductions are used as fields/properties. Go back to chapter 1.

Answer (score 0):

You have marked all methods as `static` and trying to `invoke` them using `Employee instance`.

`Remove static` from all method definitions of Employee class if they are supposed to be `instance` methods.

Moreover your method expects parameters which you are not passing. You should consider them `making fields/properties in your Employee class`.

Start reading more on [Classes in C#](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/x9afc042.aspx) and [Basic of using classes in C#](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/daniel.clark/basics-of-creating-and-using-classes-in-C-Sharp/).

Comment: thanks for your response! i will definetly read my book again. im just having a hard time doing this program based on the example on the book.

Answer (score 0):

```
Employee yuki = new Employee();
yuki.GrossPay();
```

Or rather:

```
Employee.GrossPay();
```

You are trying to use static methods in the wrong way.

Answer (score 0):

Static methods don't need an instance of the class.They are resolved statically at compile time and not dynamically as in the case with instance methods.Remove static from method definitions or invoke them in the right way